# Exibir Variáveis Nulas em um Modal

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, controller

Pessoal estou com um seguinte problema.

Tive que criar uma pagina de auditoria do meu sistema, onde ele exibe as edições que foram feitas em um certo formulário.

Quando um formulário é preenchido pela primeira vez, ele mostra todas as variáveis do formulário, como podem ver na foto abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando o mesmo formulario é editado, ele exibe a seguinte tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver, nesta segunda tela, não exibe todas as variáveis.

e o meu problema é o seguinte, eu preciso que nesta segunda tela, ele exita todas as variaveis.

este modal está exibindo somente as variáveis que foram editadas, eu preciso que ele exiba tudo, por mais que não tenha dados no campo como mostra a foto acima.

**meu JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[name="btn_detalhes"]').click(function () {
        var altaUtiId = $(this).attr('id');
        var patientId = $(this).attr('data-content');
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Formulario/AltaUTI/VerificaDiff',
            data: { 'PatientId': patientId, 'AltaUtiId': altaUtiId },
            success: function (response) {
                var t1 = response[0];
                var t2 = response[1];
                var registro = response[2];
                if (t1.length > 0 || t2.length > 0) {
                    $('#msgLoading').fadeIn(0);
                    $('.modal.Detalhes').modal({
                        closable: false,
                        blurring: true,
                    }).modal('show');
                    for (var i = 0; i < t1.length; i++) {
                        $('#trInser1').append('<p> ' + t1[i] + ' </p>');
                        if (t2.length > 0) {
                            $('#tdInser2').append('<p> ' + t2[i] + ' </p>');
                            $('#tdInser2').removeClass('display-none');
                            $('#colAtual').removeClass('display-none');
                            $('#colAtual').fadeIn();
                            $('#tdInser2').fadeIn();
                        }
                        else {
                            if (registro.length > 0)
                                $('#colAlterado').text('Usuário alterado');
                            else
                                $('#colAlterado').text('Usuário atual');

                            $('#tdInser2').addClass('display-none');
                            $('#colAtual').addClass('display-none');
                        }

                    }
                    $('#msgLoading').fadeOut(0);
                } else {
                    notif({
                        'type': 'error',
                        'msg': 'Não foi encontrado modificações no formulário!',
                        'position': 'center'
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                notif({
                    'type': 'error',
                    'msg': 'Erro na resposta do servidor!',
                    'position': 'center'
                });
            }
        })
    });

    $('.btn_ok').click(function () {
        $("p").remove();
        $("#colAtual").css({ display: "none" });
        $("#tdInser2").css({ display: "none" });
        $('.modal.Detalhes').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

**meu Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult VerificaDiff(int AltaUtiId, int PatientId)
        {
            DataSet query = _altaUtiService.RetornaFormulario(AltaUtiId, PatientId);
            DataSet query2 = _altaUtiService.RetornaFormulario2(AltaUtiId, PatientId);
            DataSet query3 = _altaUtiService.RetornaQuantidadeRegistro(PatientId);
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
            List<string> Result = new List<string>();
            List<string> Result2 = new List<string>();
            List<string> Registro = new List<string>();
            int j = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in query.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (query2.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr2 in query2.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in dr2.ItemArray.ToArray())
                        {
                            list.Add(item.ToString());
                            j = j + 1;
                        }
                        foreach (var item in dr.ItemArray.ToArray())
                        {
                            list2.Add(item.ToString());
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
                        {
                            if (list[i] != list2[i])
                            {
                                Result.Add(queryAuditoriaAlta[i] + ": " + list[i].ToString());
                                Result2.Add(queryAuditoriaAlta[i] + ": " + list2[i].ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var item in dr.ItemArray.ToArray())
                    {
                        list.Add(item.ToString());
                        Result.Add(queryAuditoriaAlta[j] + ": " + list[j].ToString());
                        j = j + 1;

                        if (query3.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 1 && Registro.Count < 1)
                            Registro.Add("Sim");
                    }
                }
            }
            var resultado = new[] { Result, Result2, Registro };

            return Json(resultado, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Os dados estão corretos no banco?

Comment: Sim estão corretos

Comment: Alguem pode ajudar?